# Echo specific row from mysql database, within set of range

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to echo rows from mysql database. So in my code user can enter a value, and then program echoes table around the entered value. That part of the code works fine, but when I tried to echo entered values and corresponding row to the value, it somehow gave me first row. While I needed exact row, which I previously entered.
Here is my code:

```
$density = $_POST["density"];
$t = $_POST["t"];
$query = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE " 
    ."(Density >= '$density'-0.05 AND Density <='$density' +0.05) AND "
    ."(Temp >='$t' -2 AND Temp <='$t' +2) ");
if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
$query -> execute();
while ($results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>";            
            echo $results['Temperature'];
                echo "</td><td">";
            echo $results['Density'];
                echo "</td><td>";
            echo $results['DensityValues'] + $delden;

            echo "</td></tr>";

                            echo "</table>";
        }
  }
```

So currently it prints the first row which is: Temp=>10, Density=>600, DensityValues=>658;
While I need to get values I have enterd and coresponding density value: Temp=>12, Density=>650, DensityValues=>678;

Comment: First, you need to sanitize those strings, and use prepared statements properly. instead of putting variables in the query, do $pdo->prepare ("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE " 
    ."(Density >= '?'-0.05 AND Density <='?' +0.05) AND "
    ."(Temp >='?' -2 AND Temp <='?' +2) ");  and $query->execute([$density, $density, $t, $t); . That is a much safer query. Second, I would create an output string, then concatenate on each row. You also are creating a new table for each record from the query. Try fixing those first

Comment: Yeah, but when I moved variables to the execute, it did not return any value from mysql.

Comment: Well then you might not have done it properly. you don't need quotes like i have in my comment. Also, you're still creating a new table every time. What's the exact output of this funciton?